# Knuth Hash for byte[]

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash, integer, knuth

Can I use the Knuth Hash to generate a unique hash number for a `byte[]`?

The normal Knuth Hash algorithm looks like this:

```
int KnuthHsh(int v)
{
    v *= 2654435761;
    return v >> 32;
}
```

Is there also a way to input a `byte[]` and generate a unique Hash value for it?

Comment: "a unique Hash"? Not unless your byte[] is guaranteed no larger than your hash - remember the pigeon-hole principle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9639/how-did-knuth-derive-a

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static ulong CalculateHash(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var hashedValue = 3074457345618258791UL;
        foreach (var b in bytes)
        {
            hashedValue += b;
            hashedValue *= 3074457345618258799UL;
        }
        return hashedValue;
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?